# ios cannot perform text to speech conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I am new to iOS development. I want to perform a simple text to speech conversion within app. 
Following is my code:

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];    
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Test text to speech conversion"];    
[utterance setRate:1.1f];    
[speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

The above code is not giving me any exception but its not working at all. I've tried multiple APIs given on GitHub but nothing worked for me. 
Could anybody tell me where I might be going wrong? Do I have to make any settings on device?

Comment: Did you forget `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`?

Comment: No. Otherwise I couldn't have used AVSpeechSynthesizer in my code.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the above code. Are you sure your device's volume is turned on?

Comment: I tested this code, it is working fine in the simulator.

Comment: Another observation - the text to speech API is iOS7 only, so are you testing it on a iOS7 device?

Comment: aksh1t: Yea, I am testing it on iOS7.

Comment: Actually the problem was, I had "USE SIDE SWITCH TO:" option set to "Mute". I just unset it and get rid of my problem. I found a similar post here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5366534

Comment: Please post this as answer and accept it, so it will help to other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem sorted..!! Actually the problem was, I had "USE SIDE SWITCH TO:" option in the Settings->General set to "Mute". I set that option to "Lock Rotation" and got rid of my problem. I found a related post here [discussions.apple.com/thread/5366534](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5366534)

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because of the `Mute` mode of your phone. To turn 'Mute On' in iOS 7, you have to follow the following steps:

- Go to your `Setting` option
- Go to `Accessibility`
- Go to `AssistiveTouch`
- Turn on `AssistiveTouch` option from the switch button
- Then a Moving Assistive icon, will appear on you device screen.
- Touch on it to expand with more options
- From there select `Device` and Touch `Un mute` option.

Now run the project and hope it will work.

**P.S:** (In iOS 8.0 this code wouldn't work, because for an unexpected bug, from iOS8.1 they remove it and it is now working perfectly)
Hope it works. :)